# How can I specify OneToMany relationship in Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django for fetching data from the join of three tables. `Table1`, `Table2`, and `Table3` all have a column name `cols`. I want to join all three tables and have to define the models for that. I can use `models.ForeignKey` but as per the documentation:

> The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default,
> Django uses the primary key of the related object. If you reference a
> different field, that field must have unique=True.

But the field `cols` in `Table3` is not unique, there can be duplicate values for the field. Then how can I do the OneToMany relationship for these tables?
I could use ManyToMany but then it violates the relationship between `Table1` and `Table2` as they have unique values for the column.

Comment: You add a `ForeignKey` at the other model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Could you tell me how would I join all those three tables then? using Django ORM

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a One-to-Many relationship in Django even if the field you want to use for the relationship is not unique. While the `ForeignKey` field requires a unique field by default, you can use the `ManyToManyField` with a custom intermediary table to preserve uniqueness between Table1 and Table2.

Here's an example of how you can define the models to establish the relationship:

```py
from django.db import models

class Table1(models.Model):
    # Fields for Table1

class Table2(models.Model):
    # Fields for Table2

class Table3(models.Model):
    cols = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Fields for Table3

# Custom intermediary model for the ManyToMany relationship
class Table1Table2(models.Model):
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    table2 = models.ForeignKey(Table2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    table3 = models.ForeignKey(Table3, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('table1', 'table2')  # Ensure uniqueness between Table1 and Table2
```

In this example, the Table1Table2 model serves as the intermediary table for the ManyToMany relationship between Table1 and Table2. It includes foreign keys to Table1, Table2, and Table3.

By setting the unique_together constraint in the Meta class of Table1Table2, you ensure that the combination of table1 and table2 values remains unique, while allowing the cols field in Table3 to have duplicate values.

With this setup, you can perform queries to fetch data from the join of the three tables using the intermediary model Table1Table2 as needed.

Comment: Could you help me with, how the query would look for the join?